# React: How to navigate directly to dynamic component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a parent component that either shows and index component, or a specific project. When a project title is clicked, the URL changes to that projects ID.

The project is then built from assets pulled from an API call using the project's title as part of that url.

How can I navigate directly to that instance of the project (if the URL was entered manually, for example?

I've tried to trim the code to as little as possible. Happy to add / omit if necessary to find a solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

var Dropbox = require('dropbox');
var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ###### });

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        imageSource: [],
        imageTitles: [],
        setProjectTitle: null,
      }
    }

  indexTitleClick(title) {
    this.setState({
      setProjectTitle: title,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
      .then(function(response) {
        // make call To dropbox API, sets states for imageSource & imageTitles
    });
   }

  render(){
    if (typeof this.props.match.params.projectId === 'string') {
      if (this.state.imageTitles.length > 0) {
        return(
          <div className="parentWrapper">
            <Project title={this.state.imageTitles[parseInt((this.props.match.params.projectId),10)]}/>
         </div>
        );
     } else {
       return(
        <div className="parentWrapper">
          <p>foo</p>
        </div>
       );
     }
     } else {
       return(
         <div className="parentWrapper">
           <Index imageSource={this.state.imageSource} imageTitles={this.state.imageTitles} indexTitleClick = {this.indexTitleClick}/>
        </div>
       );
     }


  }

}


class Index extends React.Component{

  render(){
    let titles = this.props.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)
    let images = this.props.imageSource.map((el, i) =>
        <div key={i} className="imageContainer">
          <Link className="imageTitle" to={`/folio/${i}`}>
            <img key={i} alt={titles[i].props.children} className='indexImages' src={el} />
          </Link>
          <Link className="imageTitle" to={`/parent/${i}`}>{parent[i]}</Link>
        </div>
        )

        return (
          <div className="indexWrapper">
            {images}
          </div>
        );
    }
}


class Project extends React.Component{


  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
          fileSource: [],
          projectDescription: [],
          projectLink: [],
          projectVideoURL: [],
          imageKey: 0,
      }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var that = this;
    var sources = [];
    var projectDescription = [];
    var projectVideoURL = [];
    var projectLink = [];

    var link = "/"+this.props.title;
      dbx.filesListFolder({path: link})
        .then(function(response) {

          // uses this.props.title to create link for dropbox API

          });

  }

render() {
  return(
    // renders project with files from linked folder
  );

  }


class App extends React.Component {

render(){
return(
  <div className="contentWrapper">
    <Route path="/parent/:projectId?" component={Parent}/>
    <Redirect from="/" to="/parent" />
</div>
    )
  }

}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: are you using react router?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald yes